# Googlemap markers offset on zoom

Tags: android, google-maps, android-mapview

I'm currently adding markers to a mapview in pretty much exactly the same way as the Android developer tutorial describes [here](http://developer.android.com/resources/tutorials/views/hello-mapview.html). However, when I zoom out my images offset a huge amount, for example, if I had a marker in Pennsylvania it would be offset somewhere in South America if I zoomed all the way out.  I am currently using the *boundCenterBottom* method when creating the map overlay. This offset isn't exact for my image, but I wouldn't mind if it was slightly off horizontally. However, my images are offset on both the x and y axis.

Anyone else run into this problem or have a solution?

Answer (score 0):

Try     super(boundCenter(arg0));
It worked for me.